# Fragment newInstance too much data saved to bundle - android.os.TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: java, android, exception, transactions, bundle

I have created fragment standard way (skeleton generated by Android Studio). So I have newInstance static method:

```
public static EventsMapFragment newInstance(List<Event> eventList, String accessToken, String tokenType, String cityId, boolean isMessage)
{
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putString("events", new Gson().toJson(eventList));
     EventsMapFragment fragment = new EventsMapFragment();

     ///...........
     fragment.setArguments(args);
     return fragment;
}
```

Then in, `onCreate` override I need to retrieve my collection, quite standard way:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null)
    {
        String json = getArguments().getString("events");
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Event>>(){}.getType();
        mEventList = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
   }
```

The problem is that `eventList` collection is very large, so I'm getting exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException:
>   data parcel size 592196 bytes

somewhere else in my app (weird, json is passed correctly, but system does not allow to pass anything more to bundle, it was not ease to track where exact problem is).

Because `newInstance()` method is static, I am unable to create retain fragment and pass data into it (I actually have no idea how to do that in this case).

My solution is to use `WeakReference` to pass data, something like that:

```
public class DataHolder
{
    private static final DataHolder holder = new DataHolder();
    Map<String, WeakReference<Object>> data = new HashMap<>();

    public static DataHolder getInstance() {return holder;}

    public void save(String id, Object object)
    {
        data.put(id, new WeakReference<>(object));
    }

    public Object retrieve(String id)
    {
        WeakReference<Object> objectWeakReference = data.get(id);
        return objectWeakReference.get();
    }
}
```

Then, to store data (instead of using bundle):

```
DataHolder.getInstance().save("eventList", eventList);
```

And to retrieve data:

```
mEventList = (List<Event>) DataHolder.getInstance().retrieve("eventList");
```

However, this does not work on KitKat (it seems to be working fine on 5.1 and newer). Main trouble I am unable to debug on KitKat, because of multidex, so debug compilation won't even run on KitKat (release has `minifyEnabled=true` and no multi dex). But it seems, on KitKat, this:

```
mEventList = (List<Event>) DataHolder.getInstance().retrieve("eventList");
```

is always null.

Do you have any ideas? My current solution is to check build version and pass json to bundle on KitKat (it works on KitKat, problem is 7.0 and newer) and use WeakReference on newer Android versions.

But I'm actually not happy with this.

**[edit]**
So my last try is to get events collection from parent activity. In main activity, I have following code (one app drawer menu click):

```
if (menuId == R.id.nav_events_map)
{
  eventsToDraw =  Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(events,x->!Utils.isGeojsonEmpty(x.getGeojson())));
  //....................
  if(eventsToDraw.size() >0)
  {
    mFragment = EventsMapFragment.newInstance();
    ReplaceFragment(mFragment);
  }
  else
  {
   mFragment = NoDataFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.message_no_events));
   ReplaceFragment(mFragment);
 }
}
```

`eventsToDraw` is private field, I have simply created getter:

```
public List<Event> getEventsToDraw()
{
  return eventsToDraw;
}
```

Then, inside my map fragment:

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  //Map initialization stuff
  //....................

   mEventList = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getEventsToDraw();

  //Draw on map stuff etc
 }
```

The problem is that I'm always getting `mEventList` null. After some debugging, I noticed, that `getEventsToDraw()` is called to early, so it won't return my collection, it returns null, because there are no data available yet.

Answer (score 0):

> it works on KitKat

No, it does not. The 1MB IPC transaction limit has existed for many years. However, that limit is for all simultaneous IPC transactions for your process, and so failures will be probabilistic. For example, 592196 is less than 1MB, so what crashed for you may actually make it through OK sometimes, because there happens to be little else going on with IPC at that moment in time.

> So I have newInstance static method

Don't pass a collection of events. Pass the barest minimum information necessary for the fragment to get back that collection of events. Use a process-level POJO cache to minimize redundant I/O, but support hitting the database/network/whatever again if needed, so you handle both configuration changes (process cache is still around) and process termination (but where the user returns to your task fairly quickly, so the instance stat is still used).

Comment: "Don't pass a collection of events" - I need pass collection of events, which could be large. They need to be displayed on map, so I need collection. Events are quite complex, each one contains some additional data, that should be displayed on marker click. There is no way to retrieve items, they need to be passed to fragment. My current solution is to create setter and don't pass anything to bundle (configuration changes are already disabled in manifest for parent activity).

Comment: What is valid solution to pass large amount of data from activity to fragment? We can't use bundle for that, setter is not recommended. So? My activity holds some data retrieved from webservice (it's a list), I want them to be displayed, without refreshing from server, I need draw current content.

Comment: @user1209216: "I need pass collection of events, which could be large" -- IMHO you should be saving them to disk, using memory as a cache. With your solution, the user could flip to another app for a few seconds, then return to yours and have lost all of this data, because Android elected to terminate your process while your app was not in the foreground.

Comment: @user1209216: "What is valid solution to pass large amount of data from activity to fragment?" -- you don't. At most, you have the fragment ask its attached activity for the data.

Comment: "At most, you have the fragment ask its attached activity for the data." - how to do that? Should I create getter in activity?

Comment: @user1209216: Yes. Have the fragment obtain the hosting activity via `getActivity()` and call the method.

Comment: Well, it could be simplest solution, but I wasn't sure if it's good idea

Comment: your idea to get data from parent activity is actually problematic. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @user1209216: Then your original solution would not have worked either. If you do not have the data *after* creating the fragment (when you call `getEventsToDraw()`), you would not have that data *before* creating the fragment (to provide to `newInstance()`).

Comment: Please let me understand it correcly.. I actually have data before creating new instance. The problem is that `onCreateView` is called actually before `newInstance` (according to step by step debug), I wonder why. Then it's called second time, after `newInstance`. So I have empty data when `onCreateView` is called first time.

Comment: P.S. of course your soultion is valid, double `onCreateView` call is not related to that. Sorry for offtopic